# Building Custom Files with scons

Tags: c++, bison, scons

My C++ project includes a Bison parser. What is the scons function to call for building from ".l" and ".y" files (or alike)? By build I only mean compiling the grammar into source code.
I assume that building from lex/yacc files are natively supported, but I'm curious as to what would one need to do if one has to also build some files with an 'uncommon' compiler, say a DSL compiler for that specific project.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to "teach" SCons how to process a new filetype, all you basically have to do is copying the command-line. Then you put this command into a so-called `Builder`, which will execute the required action at runtime and will care about the dependencies for you.

For a more detailed description of solutions to this problem, which actually depend on what exactly you want to accomplish, please have a look at our [ToolsForFools guide](https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/wiki/ToolsForFools).